# Extracting subset of polygons from shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile for the provincial boundaries of Canada obtained from [here](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm)

It is a single shapefile with all of the provincial boundaries inside of it. I want to just extract a single province from it, and use that as it's own shapefile elsewhere (ie. ontario.shp, quebec.shp, etc)

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You select the chosen feature and then choose **Layer/Save as...** *(you let the checkbox '**save only selected features**' checked)* and you're done ...

Right Click on the layer + **Export** does the job too.

You can also choose **Save selected feature as ...** and enter the table name.

*An other nice option is to let the original layer unchanged and only **filter it** to keep the expected feature.* *(Layer properties/Source/Query builder)*

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nice use of [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) spatial SQL queries. You can even do the extraction without downloading and unzipping the file.

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite \
  -sql "select * from lpr_000b16a_e where PRENAME='Quebec'" \
   quebec.shp \
   /vsizip/vsicurl/http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lpr_000b16a_e.zip
```

In this particular case, you don't need a spatial query, but just a `where` statement on the command line:

```
ogr2ogr -where "PRENAME='Quebec'" \
   quebec.shp \
   /vsizip/vsicurl/http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lpr_000b16a_e.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a total beginner, so I'll add a visual to help out in case anyone else needs it.

1. Select "Select Features" from the top toolbar
2. Select your feature
3. Right click on the layer in the layer panel and select "Export > Save Selected Feature As"

[image]

Comment: You can also right click your table in the left pane called "Table of Content" then "Open Attribute Table" and select feature from rows there or even based on a filters or conditions (browse the menu items within the attribute table to try them! It's worth a try.)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to separate all the polygons you can do it by running the script.  which separates all the polygons turning it into new shape

```python
from osgeo import ogr

input_shape = r"C:\Users\manuel\Documents\INPUT\Geol.shp"
salida      = r"C:\Users\manuel\Documents\OUTPUT"
driver      = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
data_source = driver.Open(input_shape)
layer       = data_source.GetLayer()
sr          = layer.GetSpatialRef()
new_feat    = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
# Loop over features:
for id, feat in enumerate(layer):
    new_ds  = driver.CreateDataSource(r"{}\feat_{}.shp".format(salida, id))
    new_lyr = new_ds.CreateLayer('feat_{}'.format(id), sr, ogr.wkbPolygon) 
    geom    = feat.geometry().Clone()

    new_feat.SetGeometry(geom)
    new_lyr.CreateFeature(new_feat)
    del(new_ds, new_lyr)
```